# Having valid creadential firebase don't allow fetch my data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

https://github.com/Tech-Vardhan/ProjectU.git
project email and password below

admin@techextensor.com
admin@123

Specifically, I am encountering an "unauthorized" error message while fetching data, and I have implemented an auto-logoff feature that is quickly logging me out during login attempts. I have tested my project with a valid login and password, and all functionality works as expected.

I have tried troubleshooting the issue myself but have been unable to identify the root cause. I am wondering if you might be able to provide guidance or support in resolving this issue.

If it would be helpful, I am happy to share relevant code snippets or provide additional information to assist you in understanding the issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

need Login and FetchData with autoLogff

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.